# Chrome text reader plugin stops angular data binding

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, data-binding, google-chrome-extension

I'm using the chrome [text reader extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/readwrite-for-google-chro/inoeonmfapjbbkmdafoankkfajkcphgd?hl=en-US). When I click `Next page` button on the page after the extension started, the scope object has been changed but not reflecting on the template.

My template is something like:

```
<div>
  <div>Title - {{currentPage().title}}</div>
  <div>{{currentPage().summary}}</div>
  <div>{{currentPage().details}}</div>
</div>

<button class="app_button next_page_button" ng-click="nextPage()" ng-hide="isLastPage()">Next Page &rsaquo;</button>
```

And in my angular controller, I've the following code:

```
$scope.currentPage = function() {
  return $scope.pages[$scope.currentIndex];
};

$scope.nextPage = function() {
 return $scope.currentIndex = $scope.currentIndex + 1;
};
```

It works fine when the extension is not using.

Comment: You may get a better/faster/more effective response by using the [Support links/contact capability from the extension's page](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/readwrite-for-google-chro/inoeonmfapjbbkmdafoankkfajkcphgd/support?hl=en-US).  The people you contact via that method will likely have much more knowledge specifically about this extension and how it might be affecting your angular controller..

Comment: Hey @ Makyen, I've just replaced the interpolation with ngBind directive which takes the update action. Do you think this is a better way to solve this issue or is there any possible problems or concerns with this usage?

Comment: I have not really looked at it.  I would probably take a look at the code for the extension to see what they were doing which was causing the problem. From what you have hinted at, but not actually described (i.e. you have not actually stated how your code is running and interacting with the extension), it appears that the issue is in the extension and they should fix it, not you have to work around their code. However, that is just the ideal. Reality is that it sometimes goes the other way around.

Comment: Actually my app doesn't really interact with the extension via code. The extension simply reads whatever content present on the page.

Comment: That was my expectation. The most likely situation, although you had not actually stated (the information should be [edit]ed into your question), was that your code was a page which Chrome is loading and your page did not function properly when that extension was installed in Chrome. Unless you are intentionally trying to allow the use of the functionality enabled by that extension, it is really the extension's responsibility not to muck up sites. But, sometimes it ends  up going the other way.